# Android calendar URI error

Tags: android, calendar, uri

I am creating event on Google calendar from my application.

Somehow it didn't work from one day to an other, it is not inserting it when I request to add the event.

I get the following error :

> 02-04 20:32:36.975: I/CalendarProvider2(20633): Sending notification
>   intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED
>   dat=content://com.android.calendar }

ERROR :

> 02-04 20:32:36.975: W/ContentResolver(20633): Failed to get type for:
>   content://com.android.calendar (Unknown URL
>   content://com.android.calendar)

Here is my code :

```
//create note in google calendar
                long calID = Long.parseLong(calendarId);
                TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();

                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
                values.put(Events.DURATION, "PT1H");
                values.put(Events.TITLE, content);
                values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
                values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());
                Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

                // get the event ID that is the last element in the Uri
                idSync = (int) Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

Comment: were you able to fix this problem? If yes, can you help me out please.. 'm facing the same problem.

Comment: It looks like, for some reason, the CalendarProvider is processing a truncated URI, without the last segments ("events"). No idea why this is the case 'though.